# SQL Dupliacte entry

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL.
I have two tables. One is !"Main_DB" not accessible for general users and the second DB "Employee_DB". Here how can i avoid duplicate entry in "Employee DB". I mean any Data which already exist in "Main_DB" i shouldn't be able to update in "Employee_DB". that should be realtime (Not inner join or other options).

Please let me know if there is any option!!

Thanks In Advance,
Umk

Comment: "Employee_DB" & "Main_DB" Both are tables. For example both are having Email column. So I want email to be checked with Table "Main_DB" for duplicates on entry in table "Employees_DB". I think now its clear.

Comment: You might add a trigger on Employee DB :  `CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employee DB on Employee DB  
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE  
AS   
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
IF Exists(Select * from Main_DB JOIN Inserted i on i.EMAIL=Main_DB.EMAIL or i.Name=Main_DB.Name ...)  
RAISERROR (N'<<%7.3s>>', 16,1,N'DUPLICATES')  
END`

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to retrieve all unique rows from source table which do not already exist in target table?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field_name) FROM source
WHERE primaryKey NOT IN (SELECT primaryKey FROM target) GROUP BY field_name
```

That's assuming you have a primary key which you can base the uniqueness on... otherwise, you'll have to check each column for uniqueness.

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct(*)` does not make sense.

Comment: No I dont want to select it from the table. See I am updating Table "Employee". While updating it should check for duplicates from another DB and user should get warning for duplicate entry.